Is there any Logic behind this error or is it just the Language weirdness?
In the below code, the first iteration runs successful, but as per the code the O/P must be 2 2 logically but as per the compiler the output given is 3 and 1 well, eventually I didn't believe it but it is what it is, try it on!!
 #include <stdio.h>
   int main ()
{
    int n = 0;
    for (int m = 1; m <=n + 1; m++)
    {
        printf ("%d %d", ++m, m++);
    }

}


Order of evaluation of function parameters is unspecified. So both 2 2 and 3 1 outputs are compliant with C standard.

@dbush I don't think the proposed duplicate is the right one here, yet somewhat related.

@EugeneSh. It includes a printf("%d %d\n", ++w, w);  case which is close enough.

@Srinidhi.S Change it to printf ("%d ", ++m); printf ("%d\n", m++); and it should make much more sense.

Um.. OK. Maybe someone will add few more relevant links
